# python: (calling all experts out there to help) how do i write a chatbot which can commands and execute a python function?

Tags: python, dataframe, nltk, interactive, chatterbot

i was going through chatterbot, NLTK libraries writeups but i just could not find a way where i provide an english like command and the response can be a python function.

For example: i could say "Get me all sales numbers for August in the Delhi", it should pick words from it and do a dataframe query to fetch me the data. and similar intelligence.

In summary, i will speak to data in english and it should convert into relevant dataframe command to get me the data.

any thoughts ?

Comment: This is a very broad question to answer. On what part exactly do you need help with?

Comment: That not how SO works, your not asking for a code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one suggestion is to use NLP  Linguistic Features

For ease, i will be using spacy

```
 import spacy
 nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
 doc = nlp('Get me all sales numbers for August in the Delhi')
 for token in doc:
    print(token.text,token.dep_,token.pos_)
```

**Output**

```
| 'Word'  | 'DEPENDENY' | 'POS'  |
----------------------------------
|'Get'    |   'ROOT'    | 'AUX'  |
|'me',    |  'dative'   | 'PRON' |
|'all'    |   'det'     | 'DET'  |
|'sales'  | 'compound'  | 'NOUN' |
|'numbers'|   'dobj'    | 'NOUN' |
|'for'    |   'prep'    | 'ADP'  |
|'August' |   'pobj'    | 'PROPN'|
|'in'     |   'prep'    | 'ADP'  |
|'the'    |   'det'     | 'DET'  |
|'Delhi'  |   'pobj'    | 'PROPN'|
```

Here you can use these attributes extracted such as pos tagging and dependency to get your desired value e.g

```
df[DEPENDENY.compound].mean()
```

You can devise more NLP techniques such as entity recognition and based on that you can move further to create queries. This may take an in-depth thinking for logic formulation but u need to explore more and write some rules.